# PHPMailer & STARTTLS not sending email

Tags: php, phpmailer, starttls

Message not sending with such settings

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                               
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = "domain.com";  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = "login";                 
$mail->Password = "pasw";                         
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                            
$mail->Port = 2525;                                    
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

openssl extension is loaded. Dеbug output is here
https://justpaste.it/1ecjw
First problem line there is 
`2017-12-08 09:48:53 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "502 5.5.1 command not supported in "STARTTLS""`

telnet says that there is  ESMTP service.
I don't know what to investigate next...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too complicated - your mail server does not support `STARTTLS`. If it did it would appear in the list of capabilities after the first `EHLO` command, which is this:

```
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
250-XACK
250-SIZE 0
250-VERP
250 DSN
```

`STARTTLS` is not in that list. It may still support encryption via `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` and `Port = 465`, but otherwise you'll need to fall back to the most secure auth option over this unencrypted channel, which is `AuthType = 'CRAM-MD5'`.

`ESMTP` just means that it supports "Extended SMTP" with `EHLO` (and all that that implies), not just basic SMTP `HELO`.

BTW - `SMTPDebug = 4` is too noisy for this level of problem, you need 3 at most. Also, you're using an old version of PHPMailer, upgrade.

Comment: Updating is not so easy as composer creators dreamed of when you don't have ssh access.. and unfortunately that SMTP server doesn't work with ssl, only tls. I implemented `

Comment: Upgrading is not so easy as composers author dreamed it of when you don't have ssh access...  Unfortunately that server doest't support ssl auth. I implemented SMTPAuthType = 'CRAM-MD5' but the same `command not supported in "STARTTLS"`

Comment: You don't need ssh access, nor composer on the server. Run composer locally and upload the vendor folder like you would any other php files. Also, the readme shows how you can install it without using composer at all.

Comment: Well evidently the server *doesn't* work with STARTTLS. The `SMTPSecure` values are somewhat misleading - they both use TLS, but `ssl` is implicit i.e. TLS+SMTP, `tls` is explicit, i.e. SMTP+STARTTLS.

Comment: You need to disable STARTTLS before it will attempt to auth - set `SMTPSecure = false`.

Comment: Thanks, trying to upgrade and sorry for multiple answers - still cannot accustom myself to local interface))

Comment: Disabled, `credentials invalid`(verify_peer=false)

Comment: `verify_peer` doesn't apply when you're not using encryption. Maybe try one of the other auth types if CRAM-MD5 doesn't work.

Comment: Just realised I used a wrong property name - `SMTPAuthType` should be `AuthType`. Corrected in answer too.

Comment: finally it happened, thanks! CRAM-MD5, PLAIN AUTH wierdly returns authetificating failure.